# What's a good way to limit the number of words that can be entered in an android EditText view?

Tags: android, validation, cpu-word, limit, textview

What's a good way to limit the number of words that can be entered in an android EditText view?

Answer (score 5):

Extend a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and register it with a [EditText.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29)

Edited:

As an alternative you could try

```
// limits to 100 characters
EditText.setFilters(new Filter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(100)})
```